# Using Facebook Graph API with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

Can you recommend a library/SDK which allows me to quickly integrate Facebook Login (using the latest oAuth 2.0 standards adopted by facebook)  with my website? I also want to access information from facebook using the GRAPH API and was wondering which is the best library/SDK for that?

The important thing here is to use the latest API by facebook and I am looking for recommendations to a C# library which makes it easy to do that?

Comment: You could take mine if you want? http://you.arenot.me/2010/09/28/facebooks-graph-api-and-asp-net/ (code is at the bottom of the article).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That list on facebook's wiki is very outdated. For an API that supports all the newest facebook technologies (OAuth 2.0, Graph API, etc.) I would recommend http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com

Comment: It seems to me that the documentation is outdated - installed the library but it doesn't match up with the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

<del>There is a list of .NET libraries for Facebook API access listed in the Facebook Developers Wiki.</del>

I'm most partial to the [Facebook Developer Toolkit](http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/).  It's pretty up to date, and if there is an API that is not directly exposed, it's fairly easy to extend the library to provide the functionality you want without having to rewrite the entire stack (instead, you can just tell it the method name and give it a collection of values, which is what most of the typed methods do).